# Probability of selecting same factor.

Tags: probability

Willie Pikette randomly selects a factor of $144$. Betty Wheel selects a factor of $88$. What is the probability that they selected the same number?

This is my incorrect approach (and please feel free to bash at me):
$144$ has $15$ factors in total whereas $88$ has 
$8$ factors.
Because $144 = {2^4}\times{3^2}$ and $88 = {2^3}\times{11}$,
the common factors are related to $2: 1,2,{2^2},{2^3}$ for a total of $4$ factors.

So the probability of choosing the common factor from $144$ is $\frac{4}{15}$
and the probability of choosing a common factor from $88$ is $\frac{4}{8}$.
Using the rules of multiplication, $\frac{4}{15}\times\frac{4}{8} = \frac{2}{15}$ which is approximately $13.3\%$

This isn't the answer; rather it is $3.3\%$

I would gladly appreciate that you guys could not only provide the appropriate analysis and solution, but also point out the error to my solution (hopefully in layman's terms :)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the factoring part right, but the combinatorical part wrong:

- The number of ways to pick a pair of factors is $15\cdot8$
- The number of ways to pick a pair of identical factors is $4$
- Hence the probability of picking a pair of identical factors is $\frac{4}{15\cdot8}$

---

You have answered correctly for the probability of picking a pair of **common** factors.

The question, however, is about the probability of picking a pair of **identical** factors.

Comment: So my solution inadvertently solved for the probability of just picking common factors that are not necessarily identical?

Comment: @cavern101: Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The factors of 144 are {1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,16,18,24,36,48,72,144}, whereas the factors of 88 are {1,2,4,8,11,22,44,88}. There are thus 15x8 = 120 ways of picking one element (uniformly) randomly from each of these sets. Out of those 120 outcomes, only {(1,1), (2,2), (4,4), (8,8)} meet your criterion. Thus the probability is $\frac{4}{120}$, or 3⅓%.

Comment: you have $8$ as well, so $\frac{4}{120}$

Comment: @d_e Thanks, fixed.